# Swift anchors of the same elements from each other

Tags: ios, swift

I have got a `UIView` in Swift

```
let postDiv: UIView = {
    let div = UIView()
    return div
}()
profile_view.addSubview(postDiv)
profile_view.addSubview(PostDiv)
profile_view.addSubview(PostDiv)
```

When i add only one of it as a subview it works,but when i add several they overlap each other so only of them is visible,how can i add anchors to them from each other.Here is my current anchor

```
postDiv.anchor(postsDiv.bottomAnchor, left:view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 40, leftConstant: 15, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 15, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 165)
```

Comment: please: lowercase the variables to distinc them from Classes!

Comment: thx. div also :)

Comment: @muescha i did lowercase the variables thus you can distinc them from classes

Comment: please post also your code how you do `i add several`

Comment: maybe `UIStackView` is what you are looking for?

Comment: Also, what's in the anchor func?

Comment: @muescha i did add my code

Comment: @LouFranco it's from framework `LBTAComponents`,very useful

Comment: you should create always a new object. name them for example `postDiv1` and 2 and 3. and layout the anchors depending on div1 or div2

Comment: @muescha what if user has 2k posts

Comment: you should better use a stackview or a better UITableView for things like that if  you have it in different rows. then you juste use an array of 2k posts

Comment: @muescha okay,thank you!

Comment: if you new to iOS and swift i would try as first exercise to use just `UITableView`. after done this, you understand the techniques and can use better some frameworks which hides much boilerplate for you

Comment: @muescha what about `UICollectionView`

Comment: `UITableView` for up down rows - `UICollectionView` if you have cells also in other directions. depending on how you need to place your cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your case i would use `UITableView` for a list of rows which you like to implement